# To be (as a modal verb) in this context

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

There is such an example: Perhaps the most absorbing thing in mine is the garden. The garden **was to mean** more and more to me, year after year. I **was to know** every tree in it, and attach a special meaning to each tree.

As I understood, to be as a modal verb means *have to*. But in this example it looks strange in this meaning

Comment: It's similar to saying ***I'm going to be sick*** to refer to a future action *(I **will** be sick)*. In your example, *The garden **was [going] to** mean more and more to me* - at that point in past time the garden hadn't *yet* come to mean that much to the writer, but he knew later (when writing about it) that it *would* become more important.

Comment: Hi FumbleFingers. Thanks for the reply. It's very useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

That is not the only meaning of "to be to". See [this list](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/be-to-do-something) for example, where definition 5 is the relevant one: used of something in the past to say what would happen at a later time.

Here, the author is describing their feelings about the garden, and how they would change over the years.

Comment: Thanks a million Daniel. I think I understand now)

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you, as a sign to future searchers.

Comment: Daniel, sorry. Maybe you'll answer one more question. In your sentences there is "would". I know that "would" can be the past of "will". And I think in the 1st sentence it is so: "used to say what would happen". Here, would is the past of will yes? We can't use here "will", can we?

Comment: But I doubt the 2d sentence. She's describing her feelings about the garden, and how they "would" change over they years. Thank you (my feedback has been recorded but I don't have 15 reputation to cast a vote)